# Brightness Settings Lenovo Y500

Tags: 13.04

Having trouble changing the brightness settings for the backlight on my lenovo y500 with a gt650m gpu.

So I followed this guide here,

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2095063&page=3&p=12434372#post12434372

I followed the instructions to the T. I can only change my brightness to a medium level and then it locks there. I'm totally new to ubuntu. I have tried all the fixes I've found on google to avail. Please somebody help me. I was happy to at least get it down from an eye blinding level but I still want more control. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this folder: /sys/class/backlight/[brightness vendor]/" and changing the numeral value of the file named backlight to 0 (or your desired backlight level). You can set this as a custom shortcut. (I added a chmod to my local.rc file to grand my system access to changing the value of that file). you can also make a shortcut for adding/substracting 50 or 100 to the brightness setting. Just keep in mind that your shortcut command should be formulated like this

```
bash -c "echo [desired numeral value] > /sys/class/backlight/[backlight vendor]/brightness"
```

If that doesn't work my backlight problems usually get fixxed by changing this line in your grub (/etc/default/grub)

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Comment: I have already tried your second option with no luck. Can you explain in detail how I make a shortcut like this? I am entirely new to Ubuntu so I don't know a lot of commands. My backlight file is in /sys/class/virtual/backlight/nvidia_backlight/actual_brightness. When I try to edit it, it says I do not have the proper permissions.

Comment: did you update your grub (sudo grub-update)??
anyway, to get premissions you'll need to use the command chmod like this: sudo chmod 666 /sys/class/virtual/backlight/nvidia_backlight/brightness

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the brightness problem on a Lenovo Y500 you should to do the following:

**1.** In the file "**/etc/default/grub**" you need to change following string:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

**2.** **Reboot** your laptop!

**3.** Now you can change the brightness of display with following command (**for example we want to set 30% of brightness**):

> echo 30 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness

**4.** If you want configure the brightness automatically during booting OS you need the following. After selecting a suitable brightness, add the following command to **/etc/rc.local** (for example if you have chose 30% of brightness):

> echo 30 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness

I have tested this on my Lapton Y500, GeForce GT 750M (**Ubuntu 14.04**)